# maven - junit tests are not running via command line

Tags: maven, command-line

i built a maven project and in the src/test/folder i have a simple junit test.
the pom structure is below

```
<project...>
    <groupId>com.store</groupId>
    <artifactId>SampleProject</artifactID>
    <version>1.0</version>
..........
.........
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        .......
        .......
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

and the junit test is as follows

```
public class SampleTest
{
    @Test
    public void sampleTest(){
        Assert.assertEquals(true, true);
    }
}
```

When i say mvn test from my command line(after executing mvn clean install),
it says

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.14.1:test (default-test) @ SeleniumTests ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
```

what is the reason for this.?
am i going wrong anywhere?

Thanks, 
Manoj

Comment: i am using the below versions for plugins
maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1
maven-surefire-plugin:2.14.1

Comment: please show the full pom, cause i assume you are skipping tests? Where have you located you SampleTest?

Comment: Search for "[skip tests](http://books.sonatype.com/mcookbook/reference/ch08s02.html)" on that page.

Comment: Apart from the above it looks like Selenium Test which are by definition integration tests which should be handled by the maven-failsafe-plugin and *not* by maven-surefire-plugin.

Comment: Are you inheriting any `maven-surefire-plugin` config from a parent pom?

Comment: @Joop Eggen there are no skip tests in the pom

Comment: @khmarbaise forget about selenium tests. it is not running a simple junit test which is present in src/test/java

Comment: @vikingsteve No, i am not inheriting it from parent pom

Comment: @KSMANOJ What about the full pom file? If they are located in `src/test/java` it means you have configuration for maven-surefire-plugin which contains a thing like `<skipTests>true</skipTests>`.

Comment: @khmarbaise My pom file is in the root. it is not present in src/test/java. Now i have explicitly specifoed <skiptests>false</skiptests> in the pom. And now it is saying the below.


-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
parallel='classes', perCoreThreadCount=true, threadCount=4, useUnlimitedThreads=false

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Comment: But ideally spaeking it should have run the test rite?

Comment: I've talked about the test classes and *not* about the pom.xml file. The test classes have to be located in `src/test/java`.

Comment: my test file is located in SampleProject/src/test/java/com/package/SampleTest.java

the classs file is generated in SampleProject/target/test-classes/com/package/SampleTest.class

Comment: i also tried **mvn -Dtest=SampleTest test** from command line, Still it says Tests run:0

Comment: What version of JUnit is defined in your pom.xml ? This is a JUnit 4 type of test, so it would not run if JUnit version 3.x is defined.

Comment: `[INFO] Tests are skipped` this can `only` be if you have `skipTests` or `maven.test.skip` property set to `true`

Comment: @Zilvinas yes i am using junit 4.x version.
and i have also set the property <skiptests>false</skiptests>

Comment: is it anything to do with the version of sure-fire plugin?